# Hide tab headers in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using @nuxtjs/vuetify with nuxt.js as combo.
I'm using the component v-tabs with v-tabs-items in my page used as grouped settings.

What i want to achieve is simple but i couldn't find the solution.
if there is just one group of settings. i don't want to show the tab header.
if there are multiple groups of settings. then the tab headers may show.

so what the code is now:

```html
<v-tabs v-model="tab"> <!-- GROUPED SETTINGS ORDERED IN TABS -->
     <v-tab class="mx-4" v-for="(tab, index) in Object.keys(content_fields)" :key="index">{{ tab }}</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
<v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
  <v-tab-item>
     <!-- item -->
  </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
```

i tried to do a v-if on the v-tabs. so if there is just one group the v-tabs will not show.
but then the v-tabs-items will not show at all. even if i set the tab property on the good tab.

is there any solution that will give the result that i want?

Comment: Did you remember to set the `tab` variable/v-model to the tab key when you only have one item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did with v-show:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-tabs>
      <v-tab v-show="tabs.length > 1" v-for="i in tabs" :key="i.name" :href="`#tab-${i.name}`"> {{ i.text }} </v-tab>

      <v-tab-item v-for="i in tabs" :key="i.name" :value="'tab-' + i.name">
        <v-card flat tile>
          <v-card-text>{{ i.text }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
      return {
        tabs: [
          { name: 1, text: 'One' },
          //{ name: 2, text: 'Two' }
        ]
      }
    }
})
```

Here you can see the live demo: https://codepen.io/ljcordero/pen/wvBXqWv

Hope this help.

Comment: thnx! that helped a lot